# Javascript can't find array from function argument

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, arguments

I want the JavaScript to find the item information depending on item you clicked on, instead of making a new function for each item.

I am trying to do this by passing id into the JavaScript function as an argument, but that can't find the variable/array.

When you run the code it outputs spikes in the console, but it doesn't work when trying find the array.z

I have also tried using value instead of id, but that just does the same.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b2h0bo29/

```js
var withspike = document.getElementById('withspike');
var withid = document.getElementById('withid');
var spikes = {name:"Spikes", description:"Do not eat me.", damage:"500" };

function itemClicked(id) {
 console.log(id);
 document.getElementById('withspike').innerHTML = spikes["description"];
    document.getElementById('withid').innerHTML = id["description"];
}
```

```html
<style>
  #spikes {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
</style>

<div id="withspike"></div>
<div id="withid"></div>
<div onclick="itemClicked(id)" id="spikes"></div>
```

Comment: `id` in function caller is a string, or `undefined` in some browsers (in `onclick` attribute).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put spikes (and future other elements) in a containing object, and use id to obtain it from there:

```
var elements = {
   spikes:{name:"Spikes", description:"Do not eat me.", damage:"500" }
};
```

call

```
elements[id]["description"];
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b2h0bo29/4/)

And an extra example with multiple elements (and using this versus id in the function call) :

[Fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/b2h0bo29/6/)

Answer (score 0):

you shoud use this, to pass the element itself, and traverse to the dom element that you want.

For example, with:

```
<div id="withspike"></div>
<div id="withid"></div>
<div onclick="itemClicked(this)" id="spikes"></div>
```

You could use this function:

```
function itemClicked(el) {
       var id = el.previousSibling.innerHTML; // Get previous sibling
       console.log(id);       
}
```

Thanks!

Edit. Sorry, i used id, while i meant to use `this`!

Answer (score 0):

It might be smart to avoid mixing HTML and JavaScript. You can do this:

```
<div id="spikes"></div>

<script>
  var spikes = document.getElementById("spikes");
  spikes.addEventListener("click", function () {
    itemClicked(spikes);
  });
</script>
```